# Move the content of one Google Bigquery database to another Bigquery database

Tags: database, google-bigquery, etl

Any recommendations on an ETL process that would be good to move data from on Bigquery db to another Bigquery db? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a question that doesn't fit on SO. It's off-topic. I won't leave you empty handed though. Try Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition.

Comment: Is this just a move or there's actually a transform phase involved?
Perhaps, a straightforward option would be EXPORT DATA AS SELECT...  You can find more information here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Answer (score 1):

You can not move. But you can copy and delete after
To copy you can actually use bq copy command for each dataset you want to move

And script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOURCE_DATASET="<bq_project>:<bq_dataset>"
export DEST_PREFIX="<bq_target_project>:<bq_target_dataset>."
for f in `bq ls -n 10000 $SOURCE_DATASET |grep TABLE | awk '{print $1}'`
do
  bq --nosync cp $SOURCE_DATASET.$f $DEST_PREFIX$f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Python client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) for example you can use something like the following (similar example than in [this official link](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#table-operations)):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

project = '<your-project-id>'
source_dataset = '<your-source-dataset>'
source_table = '<your-source-table>'
dest_dataset = '<your-dest-dataset>'
dest_table = '<your-dest-table>'

source_dataset_ref = client.dataset(source_dataset, project=project)
source_table_ref = source_dataset_ref.table(source_table)
dest_table_ref = client.dataset(dest_dataset).table(dest_table)

#Copy Table
job = client.copy_table(source_table_ref,
    dest_table_ref,
    location="US")

#Delete original table
table_ref = client.dataset(source_dataset).table(source_table)
client.delete_table(table_ref)
```

Take into account the following (from [official docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets-intro#dataset_limitations)):

> When copying a table, the datasets containing the source table and destination table must reside in the same location.

After copying you can delete the original table: